# "Decompile" Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, dom, eval, reverse-engineering, anonymous-function

[1] Ok, I don't even know how to call this, to be honest. So let me get some semi-pseudo code, to show what I'm trying to do. I'm using jQuery to get an already existing script declared inside the page, inside a `createDocument()` element, from an AJAX call.

```
GM_xmlhttprequest({
  ...
  load:function(r){
    var doc = document_from_string(r.responseText);
    script_content = $('body script:regex(html, local_xw_sig)', doc).html();
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptEl.innerHTML = script_content; // good till here
    (function(sc){
      eval(sc.innerHTML); // not exactly like this, but you get the idea, errors
      alert('wont get here ' + local_xw_sig); // local_xw_sig is a global "var" inside the source
    })(scriptEl);
  }
});
```

So far so good, the script indeed contains the source from the entire script block. Now, inside this "script_content", there are auto executing functions, like $(document).ready(function(){...}) that, everything I "eval" the innerHTML, it executes this code, halting my encapsulated script. Like variables that doesn't exist, etc.

Removing certain parts of the script using regex isn't really an option... what I really wanted is to "walk" inside the function. like do a (completely fictional):

```
script = eval("function(){" + script_content + "};");
alert(script['local_xw_sig']); // a03ucc34095cw3495
```

Is there any way to 'disassemble' the function, and be able to reach the "var"s inside of it?
like this function:

```
function hello(){
  var message = "hello";
}
alert(hello.message); // message = var inside the function
```

Is it possible at all? Or I will have to hack my way using regex? ;P

[2] also, is there any way I can access javascript inside a document created with "createDocument"?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It might help in providing an answer.

Comment: it's a greasemonkey script, that interacts with the page, but without loading the images, scripts, etc.

Comment: according to W3, the result of a "createDocument" call is a Document element, but it states it's a "cookie-less" environment, because it has no "document.location". how could I access it being doc.window ? is there any way to achieve that? if it can, this will solve my problems, since the window has all global declared variables in the page

Comment: I really think you should go with a full-fledged browser extension for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Simply trying to access a local variable inside a function from outside of it is impossible due to scope. However, using closures you can absolutely accomplish this:

```
function hello(msg){
  return function message(){
    return msg;
  }
}
alert(hello("yourMessage")()); // will alert "yourMessage"
```

Note exactly what's happening here. You are calling a function which returns a function, in which `"yourMessage"` is now defined *inside its scope*. Calling that inner closure the second time will yield that variable you set earlier.

If you are not familiar with closures in JS, I suggest you read [this wonderful FAQ](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html).

Comment: I don't have access to the original script. It's a call from a Greasemonkey script. and since I'm receiving it as text inside "createDocument" (it doesn't execute javascript), I can transverse the script tags, but there isn't a way to get the variables inside without doing regex...

Comment: yeah, I'm familiar with closures. and I just had an idea, not sure if it will work. since I'm working basically on Firefox, I will try to encapsulate in an anonymous function, then call .toSource()/uneval I might be able to get the members with it (parsing again with JSON for example)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible that way. You can introspect object's properties (any function is an object), but not before you have created an instance with `new` operator.

Looking at your code sample, it seems that your approach is a bit messy – eval()'ing script blocks is something one should not do unless absolutely necessary (a situation I can't imagine).

Comment: unless the script functions or variables can be accessed through a document created with document.implementation.createDocument(), I need to use eval, no other way around

Answer (score 0):

In your example at

```
function hello(){
  var message = "hello";
}
alert(hello.message); // message = var inside the function
```

you can in fact use hello.toString() to get the function source, like this:

```
alert(hello.toString().match(/var message = \"(.*)\";/));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [to eval the script in global scope](http://webreflection.blogspot.sg/2007/08/global-scope-evaluation-and-dom.html). Briefly it is,

```
// Evalulates a script in a global context
globalEval: function( data ) {
        data = jQuery.trim( data );
        if ( data ) {
                if ( window.execScript )
                        window.execScript( data );
                else if ( jQuery.browser.safari )
                        // safari doesn't provide a synchronous global eval
                        window.setTimeout( data, 0 );
                else
                        eval.call( window, data );
        }
    }
```

Also check out [Google's caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) for secure external script evaluation.